# Update MongoDB collection, create new field with value of exiting field, but field is an array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to create a new field, and set its value to that of an existing array object that resides in the same document.

I have tried 2 approaches:

```
db.collection.aggregate( [ { $addFields: { "newField": "$oldField"} } ] )
```

This works great, but only updates 20 documents, not all documents in the collection.

```
db.collection.update(
{},
{ $set: {"newField": "$oldField"} },
  false,
  true
)
```

This updates all documents in the collection, but sets them all to the string "$oldField", and not the value of the object oldField.

How can I update all documents in my collection, adding a new field and setting its value to that of an existing field, which is an array?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate doesn't change the database unless you are using a stage like `$out` or `$merge` as final stage. Aggregate is returning the data to the client, not to the database.

Updates can be done in 2 ways

- the older update operators (they are simple and fast)
- using a pipeline and update operators (they are powerful, can use all aggregate operators, but not all aggregate stage operator)

In your case you need to refer to a field so you need a pipeline update.
Its the same as the aggregation, just the pipeline is argument to the update method.

Query
(you can use `updateMany` instead of `multi:true`)

```js
update({},
[{"$addFields": {"newField": "$oldField"}}],
{"multi": true})
```